# What is the best way to run a query continually on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table on an AS400 server (DB2) that I need monitor from SQL Server. If a record is written, I will take the data, do some stuff and then delete the record.

Currently, I wrote a C# windows services that runs the stored procedure every 500 ms and that works fine.  But I want to run this store procedure completely from SQL if possible

I can't run from SQL Server Agent because 5 minutes is too long.

What is the best way to do this and furthermore, is there any issues with running int from a continual loop within the server?

This is my solution:

- create a stored procedure that will loop using wait time and a while loop which will exit at a midnight and will run the stored procedure, wait 500 msec and then run it again
- Run the looping stored procedure from SQL Server Agent daily at midnight

I will tweak the interval by maybe running the looping sp several times a day.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: well what's in the table? Is there a datetime column? your looping idea is almost certainly not the best method.

Comment: @scsimon, There are many date time columns, one of them is created date, why?

Comment: Well.... running a sp every 500ms seems illogical since it's unlikely your transaction will complete before the next one fires off and thus you are creating race conditions. Since there's a DT column, a more set based approach would be every 5 minutes or every hour or every whatever to retrieve the set of records you want to manipulate, do your work and then wait a while.

Comment: The transaction is written so that it will complete in less than 500ms, however, the countdown does not start until the current transaction is complete

Comment: but you can't guarantee that it'll complete in 500ms. Even if you could, is it really that important to do it every 500 ms?

Comment: Yes, because it is checking to see if a new record has been created on a DB2 server.  The records are created at ramdom times.  And it does not matter how long the procedure takes because it will not start the wait state (500ms count down) until the running transaction is completed and accepted.